# how do i get a navigation that scrolls with page and stick when it reaches the top nav with plain javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can make a div elememt move up when a user scrolls and then stay fixed when it reaches the top of the page? I already have a fixed bar under which i expect this div to stay.

Comment: What you have tried so far???

Comment: All the answers I saw were in jquery and i don't understand jquery, please i need a vanilla javascript solution.

Comment: can you give a live example or a snippet on us? so we can see your problem properly.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a sticky block. There is a (relatively) new CSS feature `position: sticky`, but unfortunately it works not in all browsers.
You can use it in combination with a [polyfill](https://github.com/filamentgroup/fixed-sticky)

Comment: thanks, i found a pollyfill solution at https://www.sitepoint.com/css-position-sticky-introduction-polyfills/